# Uncaught exception: cannot load such file -- rails_helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

Here is the error when debugging (Aptana 3.6.1) a rspec (v3.4.1) case.

```
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.6.0, debase 0.2.1, file filtering is supported) listens on 127.0.0.1:54432
Uncaught exception: cannot load such file -- rails_helper
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require'
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require'
    C:/D/code/rails_proj/engines/simple_orderx/spec/controllers/simple_orderx/orders_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/rdebug-ide:23:in `load'
    C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/rdebug-ide:23:in `<main>'
```

The error is caused by the line in the spec file:

```
require "rails_helper"
```

If changed to `require "spec_helper"`, then the error becomes `can not load spec_helper`.

The #121 line of code in `kernel_require.rb` is

```
return gem_original_require(path)
```

Here the `path` returns "rails_helper". It seems that it does not know where is the root of the app. Tried to use "spec/rails_helper" and the error is the same. But there is no error when running `bundle exec rspec spec` under app's root. The rspec version is 3.4.1, rails 4.2 and ruby  2.2.3. IDE is Aptana 3.6.1.

Comment: Usually, you don't have to require `spec_helper`/`rails_helper` from specs, RSpec does that for you if you have properly initialized it with `rspec --init`. That adds `--require spec_helper` to `.rspec`.

Comment: looks like an issue with file paths? I'd vote close since we don't have enough information to see the file paths